# $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{H}(D(0,1))$ with $Re f>0$ and $f(0)=1$ is a normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{H}(D(0,1))$ be a family of holomorphic functions on the unit disk with $Re$ $f>0$ and $f(0)=1$  we need to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family.

My main question is how to use that $f(0)=1$ to find a bound for the functions and then use Montel's Theorem. So.. hints are very welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a map from the disk to the right half-plane, in which $f(0)=1,$ you can use a Mobius transformation $M$ to map it back to the circle with the property that $M(1)=0$. Therefore, you got a family of function $M \circ f$ from the disk to itself that fixes 0.

Comment: So i can use Schwartz's  lemma. But that's a bound  on $|M \circ f| $ but the bound should be with $|f|$  shouldnt it?

Comment: Yeah, but now, you know that your family of function $M \circ f$ is normal and since a Möbius transformation is a conformal map, it gives you that the family $\mathcal{F}$ is normal.