# The family of holomorphic functions satisfying $Re f \geq 0$ and $f(a)=1$ is normal.

Tags: complex-analysis

We have a family $\mathcal{F}$ of holomorphic function from $U$ to the right half plane satisfying $f(a)=1$ for some fixed $a\in U$. I want to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal.

I also saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309551/mathcalf-subset-mathcalhd0-1-with-re-f0-and-f0-1-is-a-normal), which uses a mobius transformation to map the right half plane to an unit disk, hence showing that the family containing $M \circ f$ is normal. Then he claimed that since mobius transformation is conformal, then $\mathcal{F}$ is normal. I don't get why we have $\mathcal{F}$ normal from the fact that $M$ is conformal.

Any explanation on that approach or other approach will be helpful.

PS: I don't want to use second Montel's theorem, or the Fundamental Normality test...