Consider the family $\mathcal{A}$ of holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $|Re f(z)|<1$
Here is the entire problem:
Consider the family $\mathcal{A}$ of holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $|\Re f(z)|<1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$. Show the following:

There exists M such that $|f'(0)| < M$.
That $\mathcal{A}$ is a normal family.

I can show the first claim using Riemann Mapping Theorem and Schwarz's Lemma; however, I cannot find a way to show that the family satisfies Montel's Criterion.
Any hints would be appreciated.

do you know Caratheodory theorem about bounding the modulus on a disc by the real part (and the value at a point) on a slightly bigger disc? This should give you local uniform boundness of the family

Just apply the following to $1-f$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309551/mathcalf-subset-mathcalhd0-1-with-re-f0-and-f0-1-is-a-normal?rq=1

@Conrad I will look into the theorem. I am unfamiliar with it.
